# Bold characters merge with normal characters

Tags: email, outlook, newsletter

I send my customer newsletter with bold characters indicate that they combine the regular characters.
When i m using  tag same problem. Any Idea?
My code here.

```
  <tr>
       <td style="font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#000; font-size:13px; padding:20px">Hailed by<b>Apple CEO Tim Cook</b> as<b>&quot;the biggest news in iPad since the iPad&quot;</b> at its launch event in San Francisco, the extra-large<b>iPad Pro</b> is a new<b>12.9-inch tablet</b> as<b>thin as</b> the<b>iPad Air</b> and powered by the new<b>A9x 64-bit chip</b>. <br />
         <br />
         Running on Apple's latest software,<b>iOS 9, the iPad Pro</b> will work with a<b>stylus, dubbed Apple Pencil</b>, and a<b>smart keyboard accessory</b>. The<b>Smart Keyboard</b>, a keyboard especially for the<b>iPad Pro</b>, looks a lot like the one for the<b>Microsoft Surface Pro 3</b>, and<b>works similarly</b>. It was launched alongside an updated<b>iPad Mini 4</b>and<b>lower pricing</b> for the rest of the iPad line-up. Read more <a href="http://www.cnet.com/products/apple-ipad-pro/">here</a>. </td>
       </tr>
      <tr>
```

Note: My client is using Outlook with Office 360.

[outlook screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLRJM.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have a spacing issue on the 4th line:

```
... updated<b>iPad Mini 4</b>and<b>lower pricing</b> ...
```

Just add the respective spaces and you should be fine:

```
... updated <b>iPad Mini 4</b> and <b>lower pricing</b> ...
```

This mistake is repeated in several places, so for better optimization, just use spaces before/after every tag you use and no spaces within the tag. This was, you'll be rid of such errors in the future :)